# Mongoose - Query from multiple collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a newbie when it comes to NoSQL, so in the process of learning it with MongoDB, I decided to make a Help Desk application. Now, designing the data model, I have users and tickets which I model as follows.

```
User
----
 |- mid  (member id, String)
 |- name (user name, String)
 |- mail (e-mail, String)
 \_ pass (md5 hashed password, String)
```

I'm trying to follow this with references, the tickets will refer to the user who created them and also to the users who are replying to the tickets. I structure it as follows:

```
Ticket
------
  |- tid      (ticket id, String)
  |- title    (title of ticket, String)
  |- status   (status of ticket, String)
  |- replies  (embedded replies doc, [{ mid: ..., msg: ... }])
  |- assignee (whom the topic is assigned to, String, refers to users)
  \_ priority (priority level of the ticket, 1-5, Number)
```

Now I'd like to display to the users a list of all the open tickets; in the following way:

```
| Title                  | Num Replies | Assignee | Author | Priority |
|------------------------|-------------|----------|--------|----------|
| Unblock this URL       | 5           | SHC      | ABC    |        5 |
| Install MS Office here | 2           | STC      | XYZ    |        4 |
                                 ...
```

I just did to fetch all the tickets that where open, with this code:

```
tickets.find({ "status": "open" }, (err, data) =>
{
    if (err)
    {
        console.error(err);
        res.json({
            "success": false,
            "message": "Failure to get from database"
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Convert the "mid" references in the data
    }
});
```

This looks simple enough till now, but `data` here is an array of open tickets, with the fields of the `author` and the `assignee` as member id's where I need the names of the members.

I could of course do another query to find the member name, but assuming that there are a 100 open tickets, that would get me 201 queries, which is not cool.

I did try to optimize this thing, and got around by creating an array of distinct users, fetching the user objects from the DB using the `$in` query and then looping over all the tickets and using the got results to map them in the server, making this to just 2 queries. It works, but I want to know how to approach it properly and not with any hacks.

Coming from the MySQL background, I would have done this in a single query in MySQL:

```sql
select t.tid, t.title, t.priority, a1.name, a2.name
    from tickets t, users a1, users a2
    where a1.mid = t.assignee and
          a2.mid = t.author;
```

How should I approach this kind of query in MongoDB with Mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL query uses a join - which as you've discovered isn't supported in mongodb.

You have a couple of options, one of which you've already provided.

> creating an array of distinct users, fetching the user objects from
>   the DB using the $in query and then looping over all the tickets and
>   using the got results to map them in the server, making this to just 2
>   queries

... doesn't sound bad to me.

Second, is using `populate` - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

You would need to change your `ticket` schema to something like:

```
var ticketSchema = Schema({
  assignee : { type: String, ref: 'User' },
  title    : String,
  //etc...
});
```

Then, call populate:

```
tickets.find({ "status": "open" })
    .populate('assignee')
    .exec(err, data) =>
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.error(err);
            res.json({
                "success": false,
                "message": "Failure to get from database"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Convert the "mid" references in the data
        }
    });
```

Note, that under the hood, this is actually wrapping multiple queries -
But don't be alarmed - this is an accepted trade-off with NoSQL.

If your "hacky" way is working, I would suggest sticking with it - It's not really a hack, just a workaround for the lack of JOIN.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I went with the populate option, but with virtual schema members.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `populate(...)` method, which allows you to insert the relevant object you are after (the user) rather than the `mid`.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html